# How to update a state from a different reducer?

Tags: react-native, react-redux

How can I update the **profile** ? I'm creating where the user can change his profile.

```
Object {    
   "profile": Object {
      "name": Object {},
      "address": Object {},
   "settings": Object {
      "editName": Object {},
      "editAddress": Object {},
   }
}
```

**Reducer.js.**

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import {ProfileReducer as profile} from '../routes/Profile/modules/Profile';
import {SettingsReducer as settings} from '../routes/Settings/modules/Settings';

export const makeRootReducer = () => {
    return combineReducers({
        profile,
        settings
    });
}

export default makeRootReducer;
```

This is my code in settings reducer. When I run the app, a new object is created inside the settings object. The settings and profile reducer are in a different folder. *I didn't put the whole code*

**SettingsReducer.js**

```
export function saveEdit(type){
    return (dispatch,getState) => {
        var storeData = '';
        var editType = '';
        var allState = getState();
        var profile = getState().profile;
        if(type == 'Name'){
            storeData = allState.settings.editName;
            editType = 'name';
        }
        else if(type == 'Address'){
            storeData = allState.settings.editAddress;
            editType = 'address';
        }
        dispatch({
            type: SAVE_EDIT,
            ...profile,
            [editType]: storeData                     
        })
    }
}

function handleSaveEdit(state,action){
    return update(state,{
        profile: {
            $set: action.profile
        }
    });
}
const ACTION_HANDLERS = {
    SET_NAME: handleSetName,
    SET_ADDRESS: handleSetAddress,
    SAVE_EDIT: handleSaveEdit,
};


const initialState = { 
    editName: {},
    editAddress: {},
};

export function SettingsReducer(state = initialState,action){
    const handler = ACTION_HANDLERS[action.type];

    return handler? handler(state,action) : state;
}
```

I expect that if the user tap the save button the data from the settings object will change the data from profile object.

Comment: Where is this **profile** object that you need to update? Is it in profileReducer, in a component state or in a database?

Comment: it is in the profileReducer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Becuse you've combined your reducers, all actions are passed to all reducers. Therefore you can have one action dispatched and multiple reducers update as a result.

Assuming you want to update the state of profile when an action of type `'SAVE_EDIT'` is dispatched, you can have profileReducer respond to that type of action.

Let's assume profileReducer looks somewhat like this:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {}

const profileReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'PROFILE_RESET':
      return INITIAL_STATE
    ... // other cases
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default profileReducer
```

Then you can simply add a case for `'SAVE_EDIT'` and it will be executed when an action of that type is dispatched.

```
case 'SAVE_EDIT': {
  const newState = ... // Generate newState using state and action
  return newState
}
```